# Configure npm install proxy

Tags: npm, proxy

I want to configure node so that I can download packages using `npm install` knowing that I am inside a company with a proxy.

I tried commands like :

`npm config set https-proxy "http://company%5Cuser:password@server:port/"`

but nothing changes.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CNTLM proxy had spared me those configs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to also set the http proxy:

`npm config set proxy "http://company%5Cuser:password@server:port/"`